# Doctrine orm module error when installing on ZF3

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, doctrine, zend-framework3

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/skeleton-application/) in order to install ZF and it installed the zend-mvc version 3.0.1, after that I tried to install doctrine orm module: `php composer.phar require doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` and I got this error:

[image]

How can I install ZF3 and Doctrine ORM Module without getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run the install again, depending on when you tried this. [doctrine-orm-module](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/releases/tag/1.0.0) 1.0.0 was released to support ZF2 and ZF3 on 14 July 2016.

```
$ composer create-project -s dev zendframework/skeleton-application path/to/install
```

Might be a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38103803/is-it-possible-to-install-doctrine-orm-module-with-zf3-skeleton-app).

Comment: That is not true, 1.0.0 is not compatible with ZF3, just found out: [here](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/491#issuecomment-233918577)

Comment: @davezom You are indeed correct. It is not yet fully compatible with zend-mvc as per the [git issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/491)